# prev/next entry linking on site index

Tags: entry, next-prev, links

Recent conundrum. Building a site that will only ever show 1 entry at a time on the homepage. I want to be able to show prev/next entry links but can only do that on an entry level template (site/my-url-title).

I know I could probably use Structure but would rather not.

Here's a good example of what I'm trying to achieve http://thegreatdiscontent.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/next-previous-links-anywhere will allow me to dump tags into my channel entries tag.

Comment: While this worked it did result in a 404. What I had to do was dupe the template to create a 404 page and then when the segment_1 var failed grab the segment_1 url_title into my channel entries tag.

Answer (score 3):

I do this over at [5secondfilms.com](http://5secondfilms.com)... we only have one entry on the homepage, but still have the left/right arrows. I'm doing it the standard pagination function inside the exp:weblog:entries tag. Since only one entry per page is being displayed, pagination should always just move one entry over. Don't think any other plugin should be necessary.

Comment: doesn't your URI then change to /P5 or whatever though?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm using jQuery to pull the actual data, so the URL never changes. You could also use something like history.js to replace the URL. Not sure of how else to prettify the urls out out of the box, since you can't customize the pagination links.

Comment: yeah, I guess there's an SEO trade off as well, Google does like that url title :-)

Comment: It all depends on how you run the site. Certainly if you _only_ run your content from the index page, then you're taking an SEO hit. But at least in our case, we have the left/right arrows on the front page to let people quickly browse through our videos, but the permalinks are still required to leave comments and use other functions, so those pages still get plenty of traffic, and my SEO seems to be just fine.